# How to set the path of qt binary/html to invoke a QINVOKABLE function from a html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qt, qtwebkit

Revised--->

Based on the inputs, I have started a journey of exploring the examples on the site mentioned - http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/qtwebkit-bridge/

I am trying to understand the thin client model - i.e. I want to call a QT function from a java script. I am using FC16 on my machine.

After building on QT Creator, I get the following problem - This is a console application.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QWebElement>

class MyObject : QObject {
        Q_OBJECT

    public slots:
        void doSomethingWithWebElement(const QWebElement&);
    };

    /* ... */


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyObject myObject;
    myWebPage.mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myObject", &myObject);


    return a.exec();
}

/home/joshis1/Demo_JS/main.cpp:2: error: QWebElement: No such file or directory
 #include <QWebElement>
                       ^
```

I don't what to do next. The next part is to do the following -

HTML:

```
<html>
      <head>
          <script>
              function runExample() {
                 myObject.doSomethingWithWebElement(document.getElementById("someElement"));
              }
         </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="runExample()">
          <span id="someElement">Text</span>
      </body>
  </html>
```

I am really not sure, how to resolve that error. I am using QT 3.0.0 on  my fedora core machine. The next question in my mind is that how a Javascript will invoke my function. What should be the path settings here? Can some one explain with a good example?

I have implemented a small console application using QT-Creator. Here is the File.

```
shreyas.html

<html>
<head>
<script>

var results;
function pi_calculate()
{
       results = get_string_from_qt();      
       document.write(var);

}


</script>
  </head>
```

In QT, I have made a small console application and have declared the function as QINVOKABLE.

```
QINVOKABLE QString  Hello::get_string_from_qt()
{
  return "I am QT";
}
```

How can I do so? What paths do I need to set to invoke the function? I want to basically link my html javascript with the QT binary. Thus, I will be able to invoke a C++ function from html. I am new to the QT stuff. I would appreciate an example .

Answer (score 0):

I get an impression that you think you can do the calls from an external browser instance. It doesn't work like that. You can only call invokable methods of QObjects from within the Webkit running in the same application. That's because Webkit's javascript engine is modified to integrate it with Qt and QObjects.

Everything you want to know about this is in the [QtWebKit Bridge documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html).

There's a complete tutorial project available with a Qt install. Start Qt Creator, on the welcome screen go to examples, type `webkit bridge` in the search box, open the project, build and run.

If you want to use a third-party browser, you must turn your application into a web service server. The javascript that runs in a third party browser can then do web service requests on your Qt-based localhost server.

When implementing this, note that the entire 127.x.x.x address block is available, and you most certainly don't need to use 127.0.0.1 as your server IP. It can be, for example, 127.8.9.10 :)

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI ?? Start Qt Creator, on the welcome screen go to examples, type `webkit bridge` in the search box, open the project, build and run. Doesn't get any simpler than that.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI Qt Creator's examples screen should be a starting point *before* going anywhere else.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to move anywhere the document. Don't know how to setup the path so that my javascript knows to pickup my qt function.

Comment: I am afraid that I am unable to proceed. I have revamped my question.Please do help me here.